# Skip creating pull request action with firebase init hosting:github

Tags: firebase, github-actions

Is there a way to prevent `firebase init hosting:github` from generating a `firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml`? I'm really only interested in deploying once a pull request is merged, so I only need `firebase-hosting-merge.yml` but I get both. I could just delete the extra file, but it would be nice if I could skip creating it altogether.